# Visual Studio Windows and MacOs charset

Tags: visual-studio, character-encoding, visual-studio-2022, visual-studio-mac-2022

I checked for previous posts but can't find an answer.

I created my .NET MAUI project at Visual Studio 2022 Windows. When i copy the project to MacOS (simple folder copy) and compile at Visual Studio for Mac, everything works fine.

But there seems to be a charset difference between Windows and Mac. Special Turkish characters (such as "ı","ş","ü","ç") are not shown correct when copied from windows to mac. (shown correct at vs environment, but not at running app)

Is there a vs setting to syncronise encoding between windows and mac?

Thanks in advance.

Ender

Comment: Make sure your source code is `UTF-8`. Otherwise, you supposedly face a [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case (*example in Python for its universal intelligibility*): `"ışüç".encode( 'cp1254').decode( 'mac-turkish')` returns `'˝˛¸Á'`. The same example in *PowerShell variant of `.NET`*: `[System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding('x-mac-turkish').GetString( [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding(1254).GetBytes('ışüç'))`…

Comment: Please [edit] your question to improve your [mcve]. In particular, share at least meaning of your vague statement that *Turkish characters … are not shown correct*.